# Merge two pivots in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Now I m using two pivots to display the results. Please help me out to merge these pivots. I want the result like EmpId, breakup of Daystatus and count of [1] for that respective EmpId.

DayStatus field having 'P', 'PH' & 'A' and IsLate field having '1' & '0'.

To get the breakup of EmpId and DayStatus

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT EmpId, DayStatus
FROM Attendance
WHERE _Date >= '08/01/2013' AND _Date <= '08/31/2013' 
) m
PIVOT (
COUNT(DayStatus)
FOR DayStatus IN ([P], [PH], [A])
) n

Output is:
EmpId   P   PH  A
EC2818  5   3   0
EC2825  8   0   0
EC2826  7   0   1
EC2827  4   2   2
EC2828  6   2   0
EC2829  8   0   0
EC2830  5   3   0
EC2831  6   1   1
EC2833  7   0   1
EC2834  6   1   1
```

To get the breakup of EmpId and IsLate

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT EmpId, IsLate
FROM Attendance
WHERE _Date >= '08/01/2013' AND _Date <= '08/31/2013' 
) m
PIVOT (
COUNT(IsLate)
FOR IsLate IN ([1])
) n

Output is:
EmpId   IsLate
EC2818  0
EC2825  0
EC2826  0
EC2827  1
EC2828  0
EC2829  1
EC2830  0
EC2831  0
EC2833  0
EC2834  2
```

Now I want the output as follows:

```
Desired Output:
EmpId   P   PH  A   IsLate
EC2818  5   3   0   0
EC2825  8   0   0   0
EC2826  7   0   1   0
EC2827  4   2   2   1
EC2828  6   2   0   0
EC2829  8   0   0   1
EC2830  5   3   0   0
EC2831  6   1   1   0
EC2833  7   0   1   0
EC2834  6   1   1   2
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the issue with some sample data for your pivot tables and your desired output

Comment: Hi Tanner, I have modified the question and provided the desired output. Please help me out.

Comment: Have posted a response below. Looking at your profile you have never marked any answers. If you mark correct/useful answers to questions you ask, it improves your reputation, which in turn will encourage people to post answers to your questions.

Comment: @Tanner Thank you for your feedback. Today only I came to know how to mark answers in this forum. Previously I was searching where is the Accept Answer button. Definitely let me tick the correct answer.

Comment: Also I have one more doubt, I have received two answers from you and from @Andomar, but I cant tick the answer on both of them. Can't I tick on both. Please let me know.

Comment: You can't accept(tick) two answers but you can upvote useful answers using the UP arrow next to the 0. This will give some credit to the person that posted a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below, which should join the results of your two pivot tables together:

```
SELECT EMP.*, LATE.IsLate
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT EmpId, DayStatus
        FROM Attendance
        WHERE _Date >= '08/01/2013' AND _Date <= '08/31/2013' 
    ) m
    PIVOT (
        COUNT(DayStatus)
        FOR DayStatus IN ([P], [PH], [A])
    ) ) EMP
JOIN 
    (SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT EmpId, IsLate
        FROM Attendance
        WHERE _Date >= '08/01/2013' AND _Date <= '08/31/2013' 
    ) m
    PIVOT (
        COUNT(IsLate)
        FOR IsLate IN ([1])
    ) n ) LATE
ON EMP.EmpId = LATE.EmpId
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tanner for your timing help.

Answer (score 0):

Just join them together:

```
select  *
from    (
        ... pivot1 query ...
        ) q1
full outer join
        (
        ... pivot2 query ...
        ) q2
pm      q1.EmpId = q2.EmpId
```